# Caliburn.Micro: How to get previous active view?

Tags: uwp, caliburn.micro, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile, uwp-xaml

In a ViewModel derived from `Screen` - how can I get the last active view the user navigated away from?

For example one can navigate from the main screen *forward* to the settings screen and then *back* to the main screen. When navigating back to the main screen, in its view model, I'd like to know that the user came from the settings screen.

How can I get this information?

Answer (score 0):

The NavigationService does have a BackStack property you can access from the screen you navigated to.  While the link indicates Win81 the actual directives also setup to allow for forward compatibility with UWP.  The actual property is a `IList<PageStackEntry>` should be able to query the contents and determine the last entry.  There is also a ForwardStack.

https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/blob/master/src/Caliburn.Micro.Platform/win8/INavigationService.cs

hth

Morgan